# Linux - Colorizing Text in Files

Tags: linux, text, colors

I'm on CentOS 6, and I'm playing around with the Pre-Login file message, located here:

```
# vi /etc/issue
```

I want to add some custom text of mine, and colorizing that text.
Here's my file text for now:

```
----------------------------
Welcome to my Testing Server
----------------------------
```

I've used an example from a friend of mine, on his CentOS 5:

```
----------------------------
^[[47;31m Welcome to my Testing Server ^[[0m
----------------------------
```

I see it working fine on his box, as I ssh to it. 
But I copied and pasted it into my `/etc/issue` file and it returns everything as text.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ^[ is not a literal carat followed by a bracket, it is a control character. When copying from your friend's box to yours, the control characters have been taken literally and cease to work properly, see [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LGNET/issue01to08/lg_issue7.html#color_issue) for more information on colorizing /etc/issue

Comment: That makes sense now.  I'm required to do a physical escape, before and after.